# Inserting POST data in my sql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to send some data from my `android` application to `mysql`, but **only the last record which is added is added into my database**. How can I add all sent data with `POST` into my database? This is the code i'm using from my application to send data to `mysql`

```
private void registerUser(){
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
 URL_LOGIN,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError{
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {


                    //params.put("sid",cursor.getString(1));
                    params.put("code",cursor.getString(2));
                    params.put("answer", cursor.getString(3));





            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return params;
    }

};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

My PHP code :

```
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    //$sid=$_POST['sid'];
    //$useremail = $_POST['email'];
    //$userpassword = $_POST['password'];
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $host= "localhost";
    $dbname="offlinesurvey";

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $date = date('YmdHis');
    //$name=$sid.'_'.$date;
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);


    $sql_create="CREATE TABLE   `offlinesurvey`.`lime_survey_` ( `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,whenadded DATETIME, `code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,`answer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , UNIQUE `id` (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_create)){

    }
    else {
      "No..No";
    }
     $sql="insert into lime_survey_(whenadded,code,answer)

    (Now(),'".$code."','".$answer."');";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo  "data inserted";

    }else{
        echo "Failed";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your parameters to include square brackets like `code[]` and `answer[]`. Using the square brackets will turn the data in php to an array like `$_POST['code'][0]` for the first, etc. You can then loop over `$_POST['code']` and get each value. The key for each code and answer should line up as long as there is always an answer for every code.

```
params.put("code[]",cursor.getString(2));
params.put("answer[]", cursor.getString(3));
```

Quick example of the php side:

```
foreach($_POST['code'] as $key=>$value){
    echo "Code {$key}: {$value}; Answer {$key}: {$_POST['answer'][$key]}\n";
}
```

You can also explicitly put the key number if you don't want to trust the `[]` appending (like if there was a missing code or answer) by renaming to something like `code[0]`/`answer[0]`, `code[1]`/`answer[1]`.

The simple fix is to make sure that each key in the Map is different. You can do that by explicitly setting the index of the key with an iterator variable like this:

```
@Override
protected Map<String,String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError{
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //iterator integer
        int i = 0;
        do {
            //concatenate the iterator with the name
            params.put("code[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]",cursor.getString(2));
            params.put("answer[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]", cursor.getString(3));
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return params;
}
```

You will still need to loop over the post data on the php side like above to get each record and insert.

Comment: return only the last record

Comment: What? My answer won't return anything. Are you saying that it inserts only one record? Or that you want it to return/insert one record? Are you looping over the codes and inserting each one? Or just getting the value from the last and inserting that? Have you done just a `print_r($_POST)` to see the structure and what is being passed?

Comment: yes I tried print_r($_POST) the output is only the last record , im trying to get all data from my sqlite database and send it to a remote server

Comment: So did you add the `[]` to the parameter name like I suggested? That would work if you did. `print_r($_POST)` would show you a completely different structure. If that doesn't work, you would need to do something like `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))` and post it so we can see the raw post value being pushed over to the server.

Comment: Well , to send data from android using sqlite database , should I convert this data to json ? or send it like a string ?

Comment: Actually, I think I see part of the issue. While what I'm suggesting is required, you are using a `Map` to hold the params. Maps can't have duplicate keys and you are adding the same key over and over.

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: The quickest/easiest fix would likely just be to make sure you have unique names for your parameters. That can be done simply making an iterator variable and adding something like `"code[" + i + "]"` for the names and `i++` on each loop. You would just be explicitly setting the array index for each value in the params.

Comment: I guess u didnt understand my problem . I have data stired insqlite  in my android app . I want to send all that to mysql database

Comment: I do understand. The issue is twofold. First, you are using a Map which requires that all keys are unique. You are naming all the parameters with the same key, `code` and `answer`. Adding to a map like that, if the key already exists (which it would after the first loop), overwrites the value with the newly added value. Which means that you are actually sending over only one code/answer record. Second issue is that even if you did get it to add every value, if you just named the fields code/answer, php would do the same and only add the last because you can't have multiple keys named the same.

Comment: This is exactly my problem , im waiting for your fix , thanks :)

Comment: I have added the simple fix.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)